# Images from firebase cannot be loaded after submitting the app on app store connect

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have submitted the app to the app store connect to publish it. However, I got this weird issue the app review team is facing with my app. When they open the app, all images cannot be loaded and the error icon appears. I tested the same build I submitted on multiple simulators with the same version they got as well as physical devices but couldn't reproduce the same issue and **it works perfectly fine**. This is how it looks like from Apple's side

[screenshot from the Apple team](https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple126/v4/04/c8/3f/04c83f8f-3422-0e70-6ec0-eed405a4736a/Screenshot-0412-065729.png?accessKey=1681566628_3788433016566002291_q7Axwk%2Ben%2B3Vf8XHD7NvKsXJW7NXc5TNWbFModqkfMrlslln5fXtj4ub7krmZXdJxcmkmIu7EVFySQroHdTATBqzeFh%2BypUJ1kpSnnGgEEQ0nL7L7l3oFmTaVeI%2B6vNTuYN4POSNA2oojiqDI%2BN%2FIVTPYYGerDHltPtQHrwLUzcelPx59EOJ9aLX5%2F6WMbhn)

For the images, I'm using Firebase storage to store them and I retrieve the
links from the Firestore database.

Firebase Storage rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Firestore rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
   // Allow everyone to read the "Usernames" collection
    match /Usernames/{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

To display the images, I am using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package and here's the code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

import '../constants/constants.dart';
import '../styles/styles.dart';
import 'widgets.dart';

class ImageHolder extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? height;
  final double? width;
  final String? imageUrl;
  final BoxFit? fit;
  final bool useCircularProgressIndicator;

  const ImageHolder({
    Key? key,
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.fit,
    this.useCircularProgressIndicator = false,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return imageUrl == null
        ? SvgPicture.asset(
            Assets.error,
            height: height,
            width: width,
            fit: fit ?? BoxFit.fitWidth,
          )
        : CachedNetworkImage(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            fit: fit ?? BoxFit.fill,
            imageUrl: imageUrl!,
            placeholder: (context, url) => SizedBox(
                  height: height,
                  width: width,
                  child: useCircularProgressIndicator
                      ? const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: AppColors.darkBeige,
                          ),
                        )
                      : const AppLoadingIndicator(),
                ),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error));
  }
}
```

for the Apple team, the returned widget is the errorWidget "Icon(Icons.error))", not only in the screenshot shown above but for every single image in the app.

So what could be the possible causes of this?